# Programmatically set max image size on custom module field

Tags: 7, media

I've got a custom module which creates a custom content type with an image field (among other fields). I would like to require the image to be a certain size and a certain file extension. I've got the file extension restriction working, but I don't know how to set the maximum and minimum image sizes.

```
'my_image_field' => array(
    'field_name'  => 'my_image_field',
    'label' => t('Upload 512 x 512 Icon: '),
    'widget'      => array(
        'type'    => 'image_image',
    ),
    'settings' => array(
        'file_extensions' => 'png',
    ),
),
```

Any ideas?